# how to delete a JPanel and paint a new one in the same JFrame?

Tags: java, jpanel

Hi I want to program a next Button. if you press next the  JPanel will be deleted and a new one will be add. But both on the same JFrame. I post a part of my code. I will be very happy if someone will help me.

```
    class Programm extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {


     Buttons b = new Buttons();
     Frame f = new Frame();
     JButton button_next;

      URL file = this.getClass().getResource("firstPage.png");

      ImageIcon firstImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("firstPage.png"));
      ImageIcon secoundImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("secoundPage.png"));
      Image img = firstImage.getImage();  
      Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

      JLabel label;
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();



     public Programm(){


          f.frame();

          Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance((int)dim.getWidth(),(int)dim.getHeight(), java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
          firstImage = new ImageIcon(newimg);  
          label= new JLabel(firstImage);

          panel.setSize((int)dim.getWidth(),(int)getHeight());
          panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
          //label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) dim.getWidth(),(int) dim.getHeight()));

          panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           //frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(firstImage));


           addButtons();



            f.frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


      }



      public void addButtons(){

              b.button_next1.addActionListener(this);
              f.frame.add(b.button_next1);

              b.button_mainMenu.addActionListener(this);
              f.frame.add(b.button_mainMenu);


          }


      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          if(e.getSource() == b.button_next1){

                    f.frame.remove(panel);
                    SecoundPage s = new SecoundPage();


             }

          if(e.getSource() == b. button_mainMenu){
                 f.frame.setVisible(false);

             }
      }


      }




   the next page: 

  public class SecoundPage extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
    Buttons b = new Buttons();
    Frame f = new Frame();

    ImageIcon secoundImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("secoundPage.png"));
    Image img = secoundImage.getImage();  
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();


    JLabel label;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public  SecoundPage(){




            Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance((int)dim.getWidth(),(int)dim.getHeight(), java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            secoundImage = new ImageIcon(newimg);
            addButtons();

            label= new JLabel(secoundImage);
            panel.setSize((int)dim.getWidth(),(int)getHeight());
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            f.frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }


    public void addButtons(){


         b.button_back2.addActionListener(this);
         f.frame.add(b.button_back2);

         b.button_next2.addActionListener(this);
         f.frame.add(b.button_next2);

         b.button_mainMenu.addActionListener(this);
         f.frame.add(b.button_mainMenu);


    }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

         if(e.getSource() == b.button_back2);   
            Programm p = new Programm();


         if(e.getSource() == b.button_next2){

             ThirdPage t = new ThirdPage();


             }



         if(e.getSource() == b. button_mainMenu){

             f.frame.setVisible(false);

         }

     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add different panels in same JFrame and control the visibility by using `jPanel.setVisible(true);` or if you want to hide it then `jPanel.setVisible(false);` in above code you are adding buttons directly to the Jframe use panels instead.

Comment: Don't manage the hiding/showing of multiple panels yourself. Instead you should use a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). The `CardLayout` was designed for this exact functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> if you press next the JPanel will be deleted and a new one will be add. But both on the same JFrame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). The `CardLayout` was designed for this exact functionality.